# Validating xpath expression for syntax errors

Tags: perl, libxml2

From within my Perl script, I'm looking for a way to evaluate/validate a xpath expression strictly for syntactical problems/issues - nothing more.  I came up with the following working solution:

```
my $xpath = '//*';  ##good ; ##bad '//*?'  
eval { XML::LibXML->new()->parse_string('<X>boguscontent</X>')->findvalue($xpath) };
$@ ? print "bad xpath\n" : print "good xpath\n";
```

I find it odd that I have to put the $xpath variable thru all this - I would of thought there would exist a more eloquent method to do this directly.  Anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

`XML::LibXML::XPathExpression->new($xpath)`

---

```
$ perl -MXML::LibXML -E'
   say "$_: ", eval { XML::LibXML::XPathExpression->new($_) } ?1:0
      for @ARGV;
' '//*' '///'
//*: 1
///: 0
```

Comment: Thanks @ikegami ... 'XPathExpression' interface is more eloquent.  Regardless though of which method I use to check the syntax of an XPath expression, any XPath expression syntax error caught within a 'eval' cmd will call the die cmd and print to STDERR (or in my case since I have SIG __DIE__ subroutine which re-directs output to a log file).  I like to suppress this effect for cases like this.  Is there any additional arguments I could add to the XPathExpression interface to suppress this effect?  I checked CPAN, no luck.

Comment: Suppress the `$SIG{__DIE__}`? yeah, `local $SIG{__DIE__};`. But you should fix your buggy handler instead: Check [`$^S`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$^S).

Comment: Why are suggesting my local $SIG __DIE__ is buggy?  It's defined purpose is to simply print to my log file handle.
I was mearly asking why the 'XPathxpression' interface - when it detects a syntax error -  is throwing a die ... but I guess in the in eyes of 'XPath', a syntax error is fatal, huh?

Comment: Because it logs expected errors, and you just said it shouldn't do that. That's the very definition of a bug.

Comment: Sorry, actually, I was implying that I didn't want this effect for this syntax checking scenario because from a log reporting perspective it was prematurely providing information out of order - before I have a chance to write some other information to the log file .. that's all.  As always, I really appreciate your insight & support ... thank you.

Comment: I know. That's what `$@` is for.